# float: right markup before float: left markup?

Tags: css, xhtml

This seems like a silly question but I can't seem to get this working.

In my markup, I want basically two columns sitting next to each other, say 300px wide each.

Normally i'd markup the left right, and then the right with no problems but in this case I need the markup for the right float, to appear before the left float.

However, when trying this the left float (second in markup) always sits below the right, unless I give it a negative top marking, but this has given me issues in IE.

Any suggestions?

Comment: can you post your markup so we can help

Comment: The problem is, the markup is mixed in with a load of smarty tags which makes it pretty unsightly (damn I hate smarty). I was rather hoping that the solution would be a simple one.

Comment: You could use [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) to reproduce your bug

Comment: I've just done a simple HTML test (really should have done that first!) and don't get the bug so it looks like it might be smarty sneaking in some markup... sorry for the wasted time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it was a smarty bug as a simple HTML test worked correctly.